# How to detect page change in UIWebView and do something before it starts loading?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I need to do something on each page change, before that page starts loading/executing.

First, I tried using `-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` but that won't work, because it's also called for XHR requests and iframe requests.

Second, I tried using `-webViewDidStartLoad:` and comparing `webView.request` to it's previous value, to see if it changed. This doesn't work, because `webView.request` is updated only some time after the call.

Any more ideas?

Answer (score 10):

The request object in webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest: has two properties,

```
BOOL iframe = ![request.URL isEqual:request.mainDocumentURL];
```

If the URL to load is not equal to the mainDocumentURL you are loading something other than main doc (probably an iFrame).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using KVO to observe `UIWebView.request`?

Answer (score 0):

Make a Category or extend UIWebview that overrides loadRequest, doing your operation first and then doing the standard loadRequest.

Comment: That won't work... the page can also be changed as a result of a 30x redirect, meta redirect, JS setting window.location, etc...

Comment: Ah so you want to set up a filter on stringByEvaulatingJavaScriptFromString: or get more detailed data out of the DOM tree?